# undefined name button-tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
P_width = 1000
P_height = 600
pborder = 20
def  main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(0)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

    P_width = w - pborder*2
    P_height = h - pborder*2
    root.title("SOCIAL NETWORK VISUALIZATION")
    P = tk.Canvas(root, width=P_width+2*pborder, height=P_height+2*pborder, bg='black')

    P.pack()
    P.focus_set()
    b = Button(root, text="Next Layer View", command=start,bg="orange")
    b.pack()
    P.mainloop()

def start():
    from force_directed_graph_layout import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

(TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text')
When running this code, undefined name button is shown as error. pleas help

Comment: use tk.Button instead (I guess Button is defined in the module named `tk`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current issue, -

> When running this code, undefined name button is shown as error

The issue is that you are importing `Tkinter` as -

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

But then you are trying to use `Button` directly, that has not been imported directly. You would need to use `tk.Button()` -

```
b = tk.Button(root, text="Next Layer View", command=start,bg="orange")
```